# Cant get Twitter Bootstrap Carousel to work

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Im having many problems with my Twitter bootstrap Carousel what ever i do is not working so if some one can make a example for me it will help me alot if you dont only say no. I did post a topic and i did get much good response but it did not fix it. I want work many hours now to try to fix it. So thank you if you want to help me fix this.

Hole Side:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head> 
    <!--- START Styles --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--- END Styles --->
    <!--- START Scripts --->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mywebside/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src"http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    </script>
    <!--- END Scripts --->
</head>
<body>
    <!--- NavBar TOP --->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
        <ul>

            <li class="li">
            <a href="http://localhost/mywebside/index.php" class="navbar-menu2">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li class="li">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-menu">Products</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a class="text" href="">MineCraft Web</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text" href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text" href="#">Prices and ordering</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="li">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">References</a>
            </li>

            <li class="li">
            <a href="" class="navbar-menu2">MineCraft</a>
            </li>

            <li class="li">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">Contact Us</a>
            </li>

            <li class="li">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">About ...</name></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="box">

        <h2 class="text-header">MineCraft Webside</h2>
         <h5 class="text-des">Advanced minecraft website with server status, forums, user profiles, shop and more.</h5>
         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item"><img src="img/dirt.png" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/Wood.png" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/Stone.png" /></div>
          </div>

      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Im getting on Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close your `$(document).ready(function(){`. This is probably your issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
</script>
```

Also, You should reference the bootstrap js and css from the netdna CDN or locally. You shouldn't use the getboostrap.com url as that's not intended as a host for bootstrap (if nothing else, it may disappear without warning).

Comment: Although it's off topic, please note that "webside" is misspelled. It's "website" with "t", not with "d".